# MS Access: Take all characters before the second space

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm working in MS Access. I have a field of names. Some of them have three names (their first, middle, and last). How would I write a query to extract all characters before the second space so that I will be left with just their first and middle name?

If I have a name like John Joe Doe, I just want John Joe portion

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use InStrRev to find the position of the last space and then use Mid to extract the first 2 names. Open the query design and inside one of the field, you can click the expression builder to add InStrRev and Mid functions.

Assuming that your table has 2 fields, ID and UserName. Open the query designer and add this table. Then add both of the 2 fields to the query and add a third field as NewName. Below is how it should look like on the query design. Hope this is clear.
[image]

Comment: Does anyone mind showing me what SiliconXu means? I don't fully understand.

Comment: I edit my answer to include an example. If you want to check the SQL statement, you can change to SQL view after you design the query in the design view.